# Supressing "unused parameter" warning inside of code

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I want to supress an unsued parameter warning within the code.

My first approach was:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *UNUSED(event))
{
    MousebuttonHold = false;
    updateGL();
    return;
}
```

where the definitions are as followed:

```
#define UNUSED(NAME) USE_IT(NAME)
#define USE_IT(NAME) UNUSED_ ## NAME
```

This didn't work. After a bit of SO research I figgured out that in C++ I simply could do:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent)
{/*...*/}
```

Well this fixed the problem with the warning perfectly, but now....
the `mouseReleaseEvent()` Isn't triggered anymore at all.
So this also isn't working for me.

So what other ways I do have for supressing the warning with a in code variant?

Comment: Besides of anonymous parameters, `(void)NAME;` is a common idiom to mark a variable as unused (while technically using it in a senseless way). So you want to `#define UNUSED(NAME) ((void)NAME)`

Comment: @leemes: but that had to be done in the function body right? I can't imagine it would work in the param list. because it would throw in an extra type.

Comment: Right, in the body. Sorry, I didn't see how you use the macro in your example, I thought you were talking about using it in the body. - Ah I now see that you use Qt. There is a macro already: `Q_UNUSED` ;)

Comment: @leemes: But I want to use it in the parameter list. thanks for your input anyway :)

Comment: Then, besides of anonymous parameters, you could try to add an `__attribute__((unused))` after the parameter name, or disable the warning at least during the function signature (by adding compiler-specific pragmas before / after the signature). But both solutions are non-standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the parameter of [QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent) is a pointer. You must keep the *:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)
{
  // Your code
}
```

Comment: yes, the dreaded overloading resolution with optional virtual declaration induce such problems... one of the weak C++ points...

Answer (score 9):

**Solution #1** – Unnamed parameter:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
```

**Solution #2** – Qt `Q_UNUSED` macro:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)
    // Your code...
}
```

Actually, this macro is the *define* for the next method:

**Solution #3** – C way:

```
void RenderGraphFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    (void)event;
    // Your code...
}
```